# Load xml/xaml and define key bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is part of my xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding listImages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" Height="341" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,0" Width="225" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsHitTestVisible="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single">
<DataGrid.InputBindings>

    <KeyBinding Key="a" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/>                    
    <KeyBinding Key="s" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="d" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/> 

</DataGrid.InputBindings>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding rowColor}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns>                   
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ImageName" Binding="{Binding imageName}" Width="112" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding tag}" Width="110" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want to load an .xaml where is defined only this datagrid or better only **KeyBindings**. This because a user can change which keys can be binded.

Examle: Tom wants to use keys z,x,c instead of a,s,d. To do this he edits the default xml/xaml (located somewhere) and change the **Key** parameter of KeyBinding and load it.

New xml/xaml will look like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding listImages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" Height="341" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,0" Width="225" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsHitTestVisible="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single">
<DataGrid.InputBindings>

    <KeyBinding Key="z" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/>                    
    <KeyBinding Key="x" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="c" Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressed}"/> 

</DataGrid.InputBindings>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding rowColor}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns>                   
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ImageName" Binding="{Binding imageName}" Width="112" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding tag}" Width="110" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

It's possible do this following MVVM pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not persist a user's keybinding choices as XAML. `Binding` tags etc mean nothing to a user.

Instead persist keybindings in some other more friendly fashion, maybe even a simple ini style text file, eg:

```
Command1Key=z
Command2Key=x
Command3Key=c
```

Once you've loaded them into your ViewModel, you can then expose them to the view as an `InputBindingCollection` property, which the view can then bind against.